# Find an specific array index

Tags: arrays, json, list

currently I have an ajax returning specific data from my database, the result could change (for example the first time returns 20 rows, the second one 50, etc.) everything works fine at this point. I have code for handling and showing my results. My code is something like this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < resultLength; x++){

   //Here is the problem, I always want to check every 10 results (10,20,30,40,50,60... etc)
   if(x== 10 || x==20)
      doSomething();
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how much results will contain my data, the only thing that I know if that I want to do something every 10 results, the possible solution that I find was to add 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60.. etc. but at some point this is going to fail and it's a lot of code for my code. What I want to know is if there is an alternative to do this in a better way.

Comment: you can use mod % to get output for each 10th index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` function is what you looking for:

```
if (x % 10 === 0)
```

If you want to skip `x = 0` iteration add `x > 0` to your `if` statement

Comment: Ok, I understand, just to be 100% sure, how can I do the same but for example to get this index 3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23... etc, I don't want to skip 0 so in this case the difference is that I want every 4 results.

Comment: You can have a check for odd and even

Comment: Then you'll have to do `if ((x-3) % 4 === 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var x = 0; x < resultLength; x++){
   if (x > 0 && x % 10 == 0)
      doSomething();
}
```